# Writing array in single csv column

Tags: python, arrays, csv, writer

I am trying to write an array like this into csv column

```
x= ['syz@gmail.com','lpu@gmail.com']
```

how i can write the same array into one csv column like this

```
syz@gmail.com,lpu@gmail.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what is importing your CSV. There is no official standard for CSV but [RFC 4180](http://www.rfc-base.org/rfc-4180.html) provides a spec that a lot of people implement. If you follow that, you can simply surround your field in quotes. So in python, this would be:

```
str.format('"{}"',str.join(",",x))
```

Comment: This will only work for data that, as in the original question, does not itself contain quotes. There's no reason to use ad-hoc approaches when the `csv` module is already in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for what you're trying to do.

```
import csv

x = ['syz@gmail.com','lpu@gmail.com']
csvOpen = open("yourCSV.csv", 'wb')
out_csv = csv.writer(csvOpen)

out_csv.writerow(x)
csvOpen.close()
```

Comment: This writes each e-mail to a separate column. You would want, for example, `row = ['col1', ','.join(x), 'col3']; out_csv.writerow(row)`.